# Shell command excel vba

Tags: vba, shell, excel

I'm having some problems executing the following in Excel VBA. The goal is to run an .sql file - the issue is with the `Execute Shell` sub I think.

I run:

```vb
Sub RunFile()
    Call ExecuteShell("C:\","LAPBTN1749","filename.sql")
End Sub

Sub ExecuteShell(path As String, hostname As String, file As String)
    Dim retval
    retval = Shell("SQLCMD -E -S " & hostname & "\SQLEXPRESS -i " & path & file, vbMinimizedFocus)
End Sub
```

It doesn't run, probably due to the quotes. If it is the quote, can someone explain how they work or tell me where I can find out because I've never properly understood this.

Comment: "It doesn't run" - what *does* it do?

Comment: Just that - it didn't appear to do anything. Adding the quotes in helped though as I had expected - many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with @TimWilliams. I prefer to append `Chr$(34)` to a string because it means I don't have to count the number of quotes that I'm using. The code looks like:

```vb
Sub RunFile()
    Call ExecuteShell("C:\", "LAPBTN1749", "filename.sql")
End Sub

Sub ExecuteShell(path As String, hostname As String, file As String)
    Dim retval
    retval = Shell("SQLCMD -E -S " & Chr$(34) & hostname & "\SQLEXPRESS" & Chr$(34) & " -i " _
        & Chr$(34) & path & file & Chr$(34), vbMinimizedFocus)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

If any of the passed parameters contain spaces then likely they need to be quoted in the call to Shell.  Quotes in VBA are escaped by doubling them up:

```vb
Sub RunFile()
    Call ExecuteShell("C:\","LAPBTN1749","filename.sql")
End Sub

Sub ExecuteShell(path As String, hostname As String, file As String)
    Dim retval
    retval = Shell("SQLCMD -E -S """ & hostname & "\SQLEXPRESS"" -i """ & _
                   path & file & """", vbMinimizedFocus)
End Sub
```

If you're still having problems then try `Debug.Print`ing the first Shell argument and running it "manually" at the command prompt.